how to display rows where the line occurs > 1 in salesforce report
i have added arow-level formula ( concatdata )in my salesforce reportt that concatenates 5 fields .
i want to display only the rows  where the count ( concatdata)  is greater than 1 directly within the report .
how can i achieve this ?
Ty :'(
